# Relative Paths of File.Open() in a DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, plugins, solidworks

I'm working on a SolidWorks plugin (DLL). It depends on a couple of files (sqlite DB, sketches etc). To install the plugin, you only have to open the DLL with SolidWorks.

In the DLL are some routines that call `File.Open()` on a number of resource files that I'll refer to by relative paths. The dir. hierarchy would look like:

```
Plugin/
    plugin.dll
    Sketches/
        various.sldprt
    otherfile.db
    otherdeps.txt
    ...
```

Where the root dir. of the plugin can be anywhere on the system. The plugin can be easily loaded by SolidWorks with Open File Dialog. The problem is that once I load the DLL, any calls to `File.Open()` (eg `File.Open("Sketches/various.sldprt")`) with relative paths won't work because it'll be relative to the dir. where `SLDWORKS.exe` (SW install dir.) resides instead of the dir. of the DLL. This would mean I'll have to put all my resource files in the SolidWorks install dir., which I would like to avoid. Is that possible?

Comment: A general comment would be "Don't mess with the working directory" ! If you try to change the working directory from your code, it is likely to break something else down the line. The "working directory" belongs to the main executable. I would suggest leave it as it is.

Can you see whether your plugins related files are in any standard "relative" directory, for eg., base_dir/plugins etc ? You can then try with relative folder names.

Comment: @Subbu Yeah I'm trying to avoid messing with SW's working dir., but relative paths aren't working as I intended. I edited my post for clarity as I posted late at night, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add your addin folder as a prefix to any local path before calling File.Open().
Addin folder can be obtained as :

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```